# How to use enter key in bootstrap modal, like tab key

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

How to use enter key like tab in forms which is in bootstrap3 modal. Below code working properly in html forms, but not working in bootstrap modal

```
<script>
        function OnKeyPress(field, event)
        {
            if (event.keyCode == 13) {
                for (i = 0; i < field.form.elements.length; i++)
                    if (field.form.elements[i].tabIndex == field.tabIndex + 1) {
                        field.form.elements[i].focus();
                        if (field.form.elements[i].type == "text")
                            field.form.elements[i].select();
                        break;
                    }
                return false;
            }

            return true;
        }
    </script>
```

The function is calling like this

```
<input type="text" class="form-control enter modal-count" id="Name" value="" tabindex="1" onKeyPress="return OnKeyPress(this, event)">
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that onkeyPress doesnt register all events like ESC etc ,

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onkeypress.asp

You can use onKeyDown but im wondering why you have return in there and not just the function immediately.